# How do I make script load after jquery?

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

```
function load_my_script(){
wp_register_script( 'my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', 'jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_script');
```

myscript.js is loading before jquery, why? And how do I make it load AFTER jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

You have a typo in your code.  It *should* be:

```
function load_my_script(){
    wp_register_script( 
        'my_script', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', 
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_script');
```

The jQuery dependency needs to be an `array()`, not just a string.  This will force your script to load *after* jQuery.

Comment: ... is 'jquery' needed in wp_enqueue_script?

Comment: In the `wp_register_script` function, yes. It tells WordPress that jQuery is needed for this script to run, so it'll be loaded accordingly. In `wp_enqueue_script` it's not necessary, because WP already knows the dependencies from before.

Comment: Exactly. Sorry, forgot to remove jQuery from the `wp_enqueue_script()` call. It's not needed there.

Answer (score 1):

`get_template_directory_uri()` does give you the theme directory, but this is not what you want if you are using a Child Theme.

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will give your the directory of your "current theme", so in either case, it is safest to use.

Comment: True, but the question is about script dependencies isn't it?

Comment: Yes. But if someone is using a Child Theme, none of these answers will work. So this helps.