# Can't execute jQuery before my script

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I have a very simple JS script called `script_1.js` sitting at the root level of my twentytwelve-child theme. This script contains only:

```
$(document).ready(function(){console.log("scriptLoaded");
});
```

and I've loaded it with the `functions.php`:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' 
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( 'parent-style' )
    );  
}
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'my_script', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/script_1.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        null, 
        true 
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

Now, I read the documentation and I found that if I want to put jQuery first, I have to use the above syntax, hence `array( 'jquery' )`.

The problem is, that it still doesn't work and in the console I still get the usual:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
$(document).ready(function(){
```

There is a link where you can see the problem occurring, [here it is](http://antonioborrillo.co.uk/andys/) (error in the console).

Does anybody know why this isn't working? Did I incorrectly enqueue jQuery or something?
I've seen a few examples, like [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48530/how-do-i-make-script-load-after-jquery) and that's where I took inspiration from, but no joy.

Comment: The WordPress Codex explains it pretty well here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Answer (score 1):

Try two things - 
1. Link your js using `wp_enqueue_script` action as under :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );

function theme_name_scripts() {
     wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
}
```

Third parameter in wp_enqueue_script() function will make sure jquery is loaded before your current js file.

2. Inside your js file, replace `$` with `jQuery` as :

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){console.log("scriptLoaded");
   });

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I tried the second option only, and it did work very well. What I don't understand though, is why. Is there some confusion somewhere in wordpress generated by the usage of '$' as opposed to 'jQuery'? I've seen this sort of peculiarity before (not in wordpress though as this is the first time I used it), but occasionally when you mix plugins and your own scripts. Is that the same issue? What I find strange though, is that if that's the case, nobody noticed that so far?Also, on your first suggestion, I thought that every script had to be registered first?

Comment: jazzo - read the documentation here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers  Short answer: By default, you need to substitute "jQuery" everywhere in "normal" code you'd see the $. Longer answer would begin: You can in various ways re-enable the $ sign (or enable some other sign!) if you want to...

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just wrap all your JS code by that construction:

```
(function($){

    // all your jQuery functions here

})(jQuery);
```